# How do I display a generated QR code in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a web app that generates a QR code using input from the user and saves it into a specified file. After the QR code is saved, It should display the generated QR code in a small box next to the input box.
I am attempting to do this by having a GET submit button that goes to this route but I receive an error every time I click it.

The first block of code is for receiving the input and making a QR code out of it, and the second is my attempt to send back the finished PNG and display it.

Python Code:

```
@app.route('/', methods= ['POST'])
def textfield():
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = text
    if processed_text == '':
       flash("Please enter a value!")
    else:
       QR(processed_text)
    return render_template('base.html')
    


@app.route('/QR', methods= ['GET'])
def QRimage(text):
    im = Image.open(f'{text}.png')
    data = io.BytesIO()
    im.save(data, "PNG")
    encoded_img_data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
    img_data = encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('base.html', value=img_data)
```

Here is the HTML to attempt to display the image:

```
<img id="picture" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}">
```

And the GET button that routes to /QR:

```
<form action="/QR" method="GET">
<button type="submit" type="button">QR Button</button>
```

Comment: I'm going to assume the `<.img` was because you didn't know [how to code-format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and that's not _really_ your HTML. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Flask looks for static files in the `static` folder which is the default.
use `flask.send_from_directory(directory, filename, **options)` if you want to serve files from another directory. This is a secure way to quickly expose static files.

```
 @app.route('/QR', methods= ['GET'])
    def QRimage(text):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename);
```

Reference:
API — Flask Documentation (1.1.x) (2021). Available at: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory (Accessed: 24 April 2021).